# Nuxt.js auth module does not redirect logged in user

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, store, server-side

Authenticated user can still access the `/login` page. If I follow a link to `/login` page, I am redirected to a different page, which works fine. But if I enter `/login` into URL manually, I am still being taken to `/login` page, even though I am already logged in. What I am trying to achieve is, when the user is logged in, they should be redirected to `/retailer/account` page before any components are shown on the page (if they enter `/login` page manually).

I was trying using `beforeMount()` function, `beforeCreate()` function, following the [documentation](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/guide/middleware.html) for `auth: 'guest'` middleware, however it does not seem to have any effect and `loggedIn` always returns `false` before the page is fully rendered.

My setup:

`nuxt.config.js` :

```
export default {
  mode: 'universal',
  target: 'static',
  auth: {
    cookie: {
      prefix: 'auth_'
    },
    // Options
    redirect: {
      login: '/login',
      logout: '/login',
      callback: false,
      home: '/retailer/account'
    },
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: '/auth/login',
            method: 'post',
            propertyName: 'access_token',
            credentials: true
          },
          logout: {
            url: '/auth/logout',
            method: 'post'
          },
          user: {
            url: '/auth/me',
            method: 'post',
            propertyName: '',
            credentials: false
          }
        },
        token: {
          required: true,
          type: 'Bearer',
          global: true
        },
        autoFetchUser: true
      }
    },
    preserveState: true,
    watchLoggedIn: true
  },
  router: {
    middleware: [
      'auth'
    ]
  }
}
```

`layouts/default.vue` :

```
export default {
  auth: false
}
```

`pages/retailer/account.vue` :

```
export default {
  middleware: 'auth'
}
```

`pages/login.vue` :

```
export default {
  middleware: 'authenticated',
  auth: 'guest'
}
```

Tried all kinds of middleware examples I could find and made some simple redirection code, but, as mentioned before, `app.$auth.loggedIn` always returns `false` from server-side, so I never get redirected.

`middleware/authenticated.js`

```
export default function ({ app, redirect }) {
  if (app.$auth.loggedIn) {
    return redirect(app.localePath({ name: 'index' }))
  }
}
```

Later, when Vue hydrates the app, `loggedIn` is, of course, `true`.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Any guidance would be a huge help!

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem.. have you managed to solve it?

Comment: I couldn't manage to solve this with `local` strategy. Luckily, I had another option using Laravel's Sanctum, so I've moved on with that strategy.

Comment: i think i understood what's the problem. You are using SSR, right? Well, in SSR nuxt middlewares are executed server side, which means that once the middleware is fired, it's fired from the server so the store is empty, there is no cookie and so on - this is why you are always logged out. This happens when you directly by URL input. Instead, when you navigate directly from a link on the same site, the middleware is executed from client side, and this is why you are logged in when you do that.

Comment: That's a Nuxt design choice. There are a lot of issues on their repository about this exact topic

Answer (score 2):

Nuxt auth module has a middleware `auth` can redirect unauthenticated user to login page, and redirect authenticated to home.
I see than the auth middleware is configured correctly in you nuxt.config.js.
**The problem is that auth middleware only works on server side for SSR. but you configured to generate static website.**
You can remove line `target: 'static',` from nuxt.config.js.
Or fllow this issue to find some help for static site auth:
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/3023